Bluesky ATC simulator_ASAS unexpected behavior
I'm facing problems with the scenario described below. When a conflict is detected between aircraft SP01 and GR02, these aircraft stop following their planned routes and keep flying straight ahead. It seems that the autopilot is switching to heading mode, but I'm not certain. What could be happening? Is this possibly a coding issue?
00:00:00.00>symbol
00:00:00.00>TRAILS ON
00:00:00.00>PAN SBSP
00:00:00.00>TAXI OFF 100
00:00:00.00>ASAS ON
00:00:00.00>RESO MVP
00:00:00.00>RMETHH SPD
00:00:00.00>RMETHV OFF
# criação de heliportos
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT SIBH,-23.54666667,-46.73694444,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT SIAV,-23.56472222,-46.83027778,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT SSUB,-23.47861111,-46.78111111,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT SNIL,-23.59194444,-46.68027778,FIX
# ILS SBSP/17(R)
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT GERSU,-23.51138889,-46.73613889,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT RENIT,-23.54946667,-46.70983889,FIX
# ILS SBGR/10
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT LOMEN,-23.42690556,-46.70495833,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT GR202,-23.45160833,-46.66559722,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT LUTPO,-23.4763,-46.62622222,FIX
00:00:00.00>DEFWPT OPSER,-23.46225,-46.57401389,FIX
# TRAffic (SBSP_SBGR) 
00:00:05.00>CRE SP01,B738,STN,119,6000,150
00:00:05.00>DEST SP01,SBSP
00:00:05.00>ADDWPT SP01,GERSU,4800,150
00:00:05.00>ADDWPT SP01,RENIT,4210,150
00:00:05.00>RESOOFF SP01
00:00:05.00>LNAV SP01 ON
00:00:05.00>VNAV SP01 ON

#00:00:05.00>CRE GR01,B738,LOMEN,146,6000,150
#00:00:05.00>DEST GR01,SBGR
#00:00:05.00>ADDWPT GR01,GR202,5100,150
#00:00:05.00>ADDWPT GR01,LUTPO,4500,150
#00:00:05.00>ADDWPT GR01,OPSER,4100,150
#00:00:05.00>LNAV GR01,ON
#00:00:05.00>VNAV GR01,ON
#00:00:05.00>RESOOFF GR01

00:02:05.00>CRE GR02,B738,LOMEN,146,6000,150
00:02:05.00>DEST GR02,SBGR
00:02:05.00>ADDWPT GR02,GR202,5100,150
00:02:05.00>ADDWPT GR02,LUTPO,4500,150
00:02:05.00>ADDWPT GR02,OPSER,4100,150
00:02:05.00>RESOOFF GR02
00:02:05.00>LNAV GR02 ON
00:02:05.00>VNAV GR02 ON

I'm trying to create São Paulo air traffic with ASAS on but RESO off for aircraft flying the ILS procedure.
I'm expecting that the ASAS will just show me the conflict, but the aircraft continue to fly their routes, including descent.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.. For us to help you, provide the expected [mre]. We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.
DO NOT post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
